# text field not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, vendor-prefix

I'm working on an online eBay profit forecasting calculator [here](http://freqnlabs.com)

I can't seem to get the input fields to work in safari and mobile safari. They work fine in FF & Chrome. I click into them, but nothing shows when I type. I've been searching google but can't seem to find any clues. I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the css. Here's my css for the input fields:

```
input {
    width: 155px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 24px;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px black;
    background-color: #F8FBEF;
 }
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your problem lies in `calcstyle.css` here:

```
* { 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why `user-select: none;` would prevent you from typing into an input but removing this block fixes it for me.

---

EDIT

Here is a possible solution:

Select everything *but* your inputs...

```
*:not(input.field) {    
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: excellent, this solved my problem with a search field in a sencha touch application where the field would not turn active in safari.

Comment: Just setting the input to `...-user-select: text` would be another alternative (to ensure the input works with any global css settings).

Comment: Oh my Gosh... 2 days spent on this... thank you very much!!

Comment: The solution is best for what I need: using this to stop dragging mouse to select items on the screen.  Changing from "none" to "text" allows selecting items with the mouse.

Answer (score 26):

This still seems to be a problem with Safari 9.0.3 and iOS 9.2. What finally fixed it for me was to set it to *text*:

```
input, textarea {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```