# Safari 9.0.2 input behavior issue

Tags: html, css, input, safari

I stumbled across a weird issue today while coding inputs on a client's website and testing it on **Safari for OSX** (the version I'm testing it on is v9.0.2).

Basically, the input won't let me write anything inside of it and it seems as if it's hidden. It's not your usual input effect, so there might be an issue with the animation but I can't seem to pinpoint the exact issue.

Here's the link to the template: http://hopla.konfitu.re/objet-expression/refonte/v6/contact.html

Have you guys ever had any issue like this one?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have disappeared when commenting "user-select" and all its prefixes, the answer can be found here: [text field not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495827/text-field-not-working-in-safari)