# Safari would not allow to interact with the input pssword, while allowing input into other input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, passwords

My password input field looks like this:

```
<input class="genericButton" id="login-password" type="password" name ="password" placeholder="Password">
```

And in Chrome, everything works fine: I am able to input my password and proceed. In Safari, however, I can input my login (similar input field) but when I click on the password field nothing happens.
[This is what it looks like when I focus on the password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN2iY.png).

[And this is how I want it to work (as seen in Chrome.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwtmH.png)

This is the CSS

```
.genericButton {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,0.3);
    color: aliceblue;
    transition: 0.25s;
    width: 190px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

I have looked into others solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495827/text-field-not-working-in-safari) one but nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the problem? how should it behave? give us photo from chrome too!

Comment: Added the image. Thanks

Comment: could you remove the space in `name ="password"` before the `=`

Comment: Kindly include your codes for troubleshooting

Comment: Did that. Not the issue((

Comment: The whole file?

Comment: you are trying to do this from windows device? i think its outdated (safari for windows)

Comment: no, using a mac

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found out the solution. All that was missing from my CSS was this line:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

Works perfectly. Sorry, if the simplicity offended anyone))