# Cannot write into input field on safari

Tags: ios, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an input field that cannot be selected on my Iphone. I can click on the input but it is not focusing. The keyboard to write appears but when I write something into it nothing happens. Therefore I cannot fill out the input fields.
Is something missing in my CSS?

```
<div class="container" v-if="user === null">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" v-model="username" placeholder="E-Mail">
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="password" @keyup.enter="authenticate" v-model="password" placeholder="Passwort">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button @click="authenticate">Log In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no css here

Comment: I did not modify anything. thats why i have no css. Is there something that should be added?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8 ?

Comment: Which field are you writing to? What does `nothing happens` mean? What is expected?

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495827/text-field-not-working-in-safari

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was an error on my site. The template I was using had a style.css with the following rules

```
* {
  user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

I had to add the following for safari:

```
input, input:before, input:after {
  -webkit-user-select: initial;
  -khtml-user-select: initial;
  -moz-user-select: initial;
  -ms-user-select: initial;
  user-select: initial;
}
```

Comment: This saved me! Thank you. I was getting very confused as all the other browsers behaved normally with user-select applied.

Comment: GREAT! Saved my day! My textarea on iphone with cordova had a fuzzy behavior with this additonal css styles it worked fine on the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your `input` nested in a `form`.
This is better for validations and accessibility, and that might fix your issue as well.

Your login button should also be of the `submit`  type. See that link:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp