# input problem for iphone user on gatsbyjs progressive web app

Tags: input, gatsby, progressive-web-apps

A simple app containing only input fields with types an placeholders where iphone users cannot input neither email nor password.

Let me know what info to provide to solve this problem or please direct me to the appropriate article. I wasn't able to find one that covers the same problem.

everything works fine on android.

```
import React from "react"

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

Comment: have you checked this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889003/cannot-write-into-input-field-on-safari

Comment: Thank you! that solved my problem, I had user-select: none globally. :)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess it that is not Gatsby related, it seems a behavior (CSS) issue. Try adding these rules:

```
input, input:before, input:after {
  -webkit-user-select: initial;
  -khtml-user-select: initial;
  -moz-user-select: initial;
  -ms-user-select: initial;
  user-select: initial;
}
```

*Source: [Cannot write into input field on safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889003/cannot-write-into-input-field-on-safari)*

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact problem, I had user-select: none globaly.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue :)